# TortoiseGit error: waitpid for git credential-manager get failed: No child processes

Tags: git, tortoisegit

When I execute commands like Pull and Push the following error is generated on the TortoiseGit console:

> error: waitpid for git credential-manager get failed: No child processes.

It runs correctly when I use git bash.

Comment: error: waitpid for git credential-manager get failed: No child processes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check which Git your TortoiseGit is using:

- the internal one
- the system one.

If it is the system one (the Git you have installed independently of Git), the latest [Git for Windows 2.22](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.22.0.windows.1) (assuming here Windows) does have a new popup asking you to chose a manager. That might be an issue.

Try again to launch TortoiseGit after typing first:

```
git config --global credential.helper manager
```